# Intuitive way to use 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Lets take a simplistic example where I have the data array

```
A = np.asarray([[1,3], [2,4]])
```

And this data is to be transformed into another form following a simple transformation:

```
Q = np.asarray([[-0.5,1], [1,0.5]])
B = np.dot(Q,np.dot(A,Q.T))
print B
```

Now assume that I have a set of data that takes the form of a 2d array for several time steps. For simplicity again assume that this data is just `A` copied for 3 time steps. We can represent this data as a 3d array with dimensions `(2,2,N)` where `N =3` in this case. The third dimension then represents the time index of the data. Now it would be natural to demand to have a simple way of transforming the data as above but for each time step, by an intuitive multiplication of 3d arrays, however I have only been able to make the following work which is non-intuitive:

```
# Create the 3d data array
AA = np.tile(A,(3,1,1)) # shape (3,2,2)
BB = np.dot(Q,np.dot(AA,Q.T))

print np.all( BB[:,0,:] == B ) # Returns true
```

So with this method I don't have to recast the `Q` array to make it work, but now the second dimension acts as the "time" index which is a bit counter intuitive since in `AA` it was the first dimension that denoted the time... Ideally I would like a solution in which both `AA` and `BB` have the time index in the third dimension!

Edit:

Since `dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])` from docs I am wondering if what I am trying to achieve is not possible? It seems strange as this should be a relatively common thing one may desire...

Comment: With `numpy` the `1st axis is the outermost one, so a `(N,2,2)` shape might be more natural, produced for example by `np.array([A1,A2,A3])`, the joining of 3 2x2 arrays.  But this sort of `dot` rotation can be made to work with (2,N,2) or (2,2,N) as well.  `dot` normally works with last dim and 2nd to the last dim.  `np.matmul` and `np.einsum` are alternatives.

Comment: @hpaulj  So how would I carry out the array multiplication in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [91]: A=np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])
In [92]: Q=np.array([[-.5,1],[1,.5]])
In [93]: B=np.dot(Q,np.dot(A,Q.T))
In [94]: B
Out[94]: 
array([[ 1.75,  2.75],
       [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]])
```

The same calculation with `einsum`:

```
In [95]: np.einsum('ij,jk,kl',Q,A,Q)
Out[95]: 
array([[ 1.75,  2.75],
       [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]])
```

If I make several copies of `A` - on a new 1st dimension:

```
In [96]: AA = np.array([A,A,A])
In [97]: AA.shape
Out[97]: (3, 2, 2)
...
In [99]: BB=np.einsum('ij,pjk,kl->pil',Q,AA,Q)
In [100]: BB
Out[100]: 
array([[[ 1.75,  2.75],
        [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]],

       [[ 1.75,  2.75],
        [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]],

       [[ 1.75,  2.75],
        [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]]])
```

`BB` has a (3,2,2) shape.

The newish `matmul` (@ operator) lets me do the same thing

```
In [102]: Q@A@Q.T
Out[102]: 
array([[ 1.75,  2.75],
       [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]])
In [103]: Q@AA@Q.T
Out[103]: 
array([[[ 1.75,  2.75],
        [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]],

       [[ 1.75,  2.75],
        [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]],

       [[ 1.75,  2.75],
        [ 4.  ,  4.5 ]]])
```

With `einsum` it is just as easy to work with the last dimension:

```
In [104]: AA3=np.stack([A,A,A],-1)    # newish np.stack
In [105]: AA3.shape
Out[105]: (2, 2, 3)
In [106]: np.einsum('ij,jkp,kl->ilp',Q,AA3,Q)
Out[106]: 
array([[[ 1.75,  1.75,  1.75],
        [ 2.75,  2.75,  2.75]],

       [[ 4.  ,  4.  ,  4.  ],
        [ 4.5 ,  4.5 ,  4.5 ]]])
In [107]: _.shape
Out[107]: (2, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Very nice - I was just experimenting with `einsum`! It looks like it is a very general flexible way of doing summations. Do you have any knowledge off the top of your head how it compares in performance to dot?

Comment: Also one more thing - your first solution is slightly incorrect it should be `BB=np.einsum('ij,pjk,lk->pil',Q,AA,Q)` although in this case it doesn't flag an issue because `Q` is symmetric!

Comment: True; I mentally made a note that the `Q.T` required switching the index order, but didn't verify it.

Comment: Yes I figured! Answer really made me understand that einsum convention so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with your definition of "intuitive" - to me it seems more natural to represent the time index by the first dimension of the array. Since numpy arrays are [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) by default, this ordering of the dimensions will give you better [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) for each 2x2 submatrix, since all of the elements will be in adjacent memory addresses.

Nonetheless, it's possible to adapt your example to work for a `(2, 2, N)` array by using [`np.matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) and transposing each of the intermediate arrays:

```
CC = np.repeat(A[..., None], 3, -1)   # shape (2, 2, 3)
DD = np.matmul(Q.T, np.matmul(CC.T, Q)).T

print(DD.shape)
# (2, 2, 3)

print(repr(DD))
# array([[[ 1.75,  1.75,  1.75],
#         [ 2.75,  2.75,  2.75]],

#        [[ 4.  ,  4.  ,  4.  ],
#         [ 4.5 ,  4.5 ,  4.5 ]]])
```

In Python 3.5+ you can make this even more compact by using the [`@` operator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) as shorthand for `np.matmul`:

```
DD = (Q.T @ (CC.T @ Q)).T
```